# When i run the Xamarin Form Project getting error can't debug

Tags: c#, xamarin

It is showing errors in Xamarin Project when i try to run it and deploy it in the Android emulator and this error occurs for HOCKEY App. I really don't know how to sort it out so please suggest a way to make it debug

```
    C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\lib\proguard.jar" -include C:\AndroidLink\android-sdk\\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg -include proguard.cfg "-injars 'obj\Debug\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.1\mono.android.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\HockeySDK.AndroidBindings\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar'" "-libraryjars 'C:\AndroidLink\android-sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar'" -outjars "obj\Debug\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar" -optimizations !code/allocation/variable 

1>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\\bin\java.exe -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\proguard\lib\proguard.jar" -include C:\AndroidLink\android-sdk\\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_xamarin.cfg -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_project_references.cfg -include obj\Debug\proguard\proguard_project_primary.cfg "-injars 'obj\Debug\proguard\__proguard_input__.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v7.1\mono.android.jar';'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\android-support-multidex.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\FormsViewGroup\library_project_imports\formsviewgroup.jar';'obj\Debug\__library_projects__\HockeySDK.AndroidBindings\library_project_imports\bin\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v4\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter\23.3.0.0\embedded\libs\internal_impl-23.3.0.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable\23.3.0.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Analytics\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar';'C:\Users\sandeepsubbiahs\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement\8.4.0\embedded\classes.jar'" "-libraryjars 'C:\AndroidLink\android-sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar'" -outjars "obj\Debug\proguard\__proguard_output__.jar" -optimizations !code/allocation/variable*** 
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.CrashManager: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.ExpiryInfoActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$2: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$2: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$2: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$FeedbackHandler: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$FeedbackHandler: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$FeedbackHandler: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.FeedbackActivity$FeedbackHandler: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.LoginActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.PaintActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity$3: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity$3: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateActivity$3: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment$1: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment$1: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.UpdateFragment$1: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.CheckUpdateTaskWithUI: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.DownloadFileTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.SendFeedbackTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.SendFeedbackTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.SendFeedbackTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.tasks.SendFeedbackTask: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.utils.Util: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.utils.Util: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.utils.Util: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$string
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.AttachmentView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$layout
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$id
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R$color
        1>net.hockeyapp.android.views.FeedbackMessageView: can't find referenced class net.hockeyapp.android.R
        1>there were 153 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
        1>"java.exe" exited with code 1.
```

Comment: First of all the error is so unreadable there is no way anyone can help you

Comment: Flagged for being very low quality.

Comment: @dimmik Is it readable now ?

Comment: @DanielShillcock I was editing and you flagged it

Comment: @DanielShillcock yes you can say is better but i can't help you. I only comment just to make it better looking